# How to fetch latitude and longitude in google maps?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I stored some lattitude and longitude on google map now i want add on google

I tried to read lattitude and longitude into `array` than i tried to read the `array` into google map but throw that the `array` is *unitialized*

```
JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                if (response.length() > 0) {
                    phone = new String[response.length()];
                    liti = new double[response.length()];
                    longt = new double[response.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            phone[i] = jsonObject.getString("phone").toString();
                            liti[i] = ((double) jsonObject.getDouble("latitude"));
                            longt[i] = ((double) jsonObject.getDouble("longitude"));
                            Toast.makeText(context, longt[i]+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
```

i want to add these lititude and longitude onto google map

Comment: It looks like you are not parsing your response properly. If you could make an api reqest and update your question with json response example, than I could help.

Comment: Please show me the error

Comment: i solved the error thanks all